# Offset and Match using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in the data sheet and another output table in the main sheet.

The cells have weird formatting which i have not yet solved but I need to match the value e.g. A in col 1 and then get the value 0.17. Likewise, I need to do it with B and C as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Excel LOOKUP function can be used here.

Example (in one cell of the main sheet):
=LOOKUP("A";'Data Sheet'!A2:A7;'Data Sheet'!H2:H7)

More information about function:
http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324986

For multiple matches it returns the last found value.